# copying from multiple columns to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem:

600 columns, with 25 rows of data.

I need to copy the data from *columns 2 to 600* and place them at the end of the content in *column1*.

Any information in how I can do this will be greatly appreciated.

**Here's the code I currently use:**

```
Sub test()

  Dim rng1 As Range 
  Dim rng2 As Range 
  Dim cl As Range 
  Dim r As Long 

  Set rng1 = Range("A1", Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)) 
  Set rng2 = Range("B1", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)) 
  r = rng1.Rows.Count + 1

  For Each cl In rng2 
    Cells(r, 1).Value = cl.Value 
    r = r + 1 
  Next 

End Sub
```

The problem is it only copies `B` column and not the other columns (eg. C, D, E, etc.)

Comment: hi, it would be great if you can include what you've tried and where are you stuck. If in your attemp you encounter errors, please clearly state it as well.

Comment: I am a novice when it comes to scripting. I have trying to solve this problem till I came across some solution on this site as follows:

Comment: Sub test()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim r As Long

Set rng1 = Range("A1", Range("A1048576").End(xlUp))
Set rng2 = Range("B1", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))

r = rng1.Rows.Count + 1

For Each cl In rng2
    Cells(r, 1).Value = cl.Value
    r = r + 1
Next

End Sub

Comment: The problem I had with this script is that it only copies the B column but not the other columns (c. d, e, etc)

Comment: This is on the same sheet? what do you mean by copying all columns on to column1? Concatenate the data or just copy the entire row? If the latter, see my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need I guess:

**Tested:**

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws as WorkSheet
Dim C1_lrow, C2_lrow, lcolumn, i as Long
Dim rng as Range

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change this to what you have

With ws
    C2_lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
    lcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & C2_lrow)
End With

For i = 0 to lcolumn - 1
    C1_lrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
    rng.Offset(0, i).copy ws.Range("A" & C1_lrow + 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Try if it works for you.

Comment: Your solution is perfect does exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: What about the case where you first had to arranged the data from rows to column (transpose) and then copy the second, third etc columns to join or append to the first column?

Answer (score 0):

I would not solve this in Excel only.

1. Save the file as a csv-file
2. Open the file with a editor-like (e.g. Notepad++)
3. Replace ";" with " " or ", "
4. Save the file
5. Open the file with Excel

Now you have only 1 column left.

If you need this to be done automatic, you'll need a script.

Comment: May be I need to clarify my problem. The contents of my table in excel is like: A1..A25; B2..B25, C2..C25, D2..D25,.... and I want copy B2..B25 and paste this at A26,..A50 and the copy C2..C25 and paste is at A51..A75 etc. I need a script for this.